# Quick Node RPC For Minting

Tags: nft, rpc, mint, candy-machine-v3

Can we use quicknode rpc to run a metaplex candymachine? i've used ankr before but it couldnt even be used

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a paid Quicknode RPC should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a QuickNode RPC but for best performance and cheaper prices I suggest Helius or Shyft RPCs

If it's a smaller mint you can even get by with a free RPC!

Helius: https://dev.helius.xyz/dashboard/app
Shyft: https://shyft.to/get-api-key